# Why Jupyter Notebook does not allow downloading folders?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Why Jupyter Notebook does not allow downloading the entire folder?

Under one of my Jupyter notebook directory, I have a folder of images I use for training my model. It seems that in Jupyter notebook it allows for download of individual files but not an entire folder or more than 1 file at a time.

Is there any way I can download the entire training data set? See screenshots below.

1 File:

[image]

More than 1 files:

[image]

A folder:

[image]

Comment: This functionality is obviously not implemented yet - you could create an issue on their github (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook) to request this feature

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48122744/how-to-download-all-files-and-folder-hierarchy-from-jupyter-notebook).